# How to read a matrix from the console and print the sum of all matrix elements

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm learning C#, and now I am on Multidimensional Arrays. I want to write a program that **reads a matrix** from the console and print:

- Count of **rows**
- Count of **columns**
- Sum of **all matrix elements**

[image]

So, on the next **[rows]** lines I will get elements for each column separated with comma and space. I made a foreach for the sum but I do not understand how to insert the elements into the matrix. I would be very grateful if you could help me!

```
int[] dimensions = Console.ReadLine()
.Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(int.Parse)
.ToArray(); 

int rows = dimensions[0];
int columns = dimensions[1];

int[,] matrix = new int[rows,columns];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{ 
    int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();
//I do not know how to add the elements here
}

int sum = 0;
foreach (var element in matrix)
{
    sum += element;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in 2-d array are being accessed using two indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{ 
    int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        matrix[i,j]=numbers[j];
    }
}

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        sum += matrix[i,j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am searching for a solution with Multidimensional Arrays because this is what I am learning at the moment.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova , ok, I've updated my answer with 2-dimensional array

Comment: @Renat, @nikolDimitrova no need to use 2D array, just `Linq` `sum()` function will  work for you...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq `Sum()` to calculate sum for all rows

As you are iterating through each row of input data already, then you can assign one temparary variable called `sum =0` and for each row calculate sum of all numbers of that row and add it to temporary variable i.e. `sum`.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{ 
    int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();
    sum += numbers.Sum(); //Calculate sum of all numbers in a row and add it to existing sum variable.
//I do not know how to add the elements here
}

Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers" + sum); //print sum of all numbers i.e. 76
```

Comment: @NikolDimitrova, kindly check my answer, elegant approach to calculate sum

Comment: Thank you for your response! As I said, I want to **insert the elements into a matrix** and **then** calculate the **sum**.