# Square with Maximum Sum

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am learning C#, and I am doing Multidimensional Arrays at the moment. I want to write a program that **reads a matrix** and then finds the biggest sum of **2x2 submatrix** and prints it.

[image: Square with Maximum Sum]

```
int[] dimensions = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();

int rows = dimensions[0];
int columns = dimensions[1];

int[,] matrix = new int[rows,columns];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
     int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
                .Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToArray();

     for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
     {
          matrix[i, j] = numbers[j];
     }
 }

int maxSum = int.MinValue;
        int selectedRow = -1;
        int selectedCol = -1;

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; col++)
            {
                int currentSum = matrix[row, col] + matrix[row, col + 1] + matrix[row + 1, col] + matrix[row + 1, col + 1];

                if (currentSum > maxSum)
                {
                    maxSum = currentSum;
                    selectedRow = row;
                    selectedCol = col;
                }

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{matrix[selectedRow, selectedCol]} {matrix[selectedRow, selectedCol + 1]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{matrix[selectedRow + 1, selectedCol]} {matrix[selectedRow + 1, selectedCol + 1]}");
        Console.WriteLine(maxSum);
```

So, I read the matrix, but I am not sure how to **start finding the submatrices** and **compare their sums**. I would be very grateful if you could give me some hints.

Comment: A great start would be writing a function which is able to check a 2x2 matrix by passing the matrix and a rowOffset, columnOffset and returns the sum. Then make a loop to check row.Length-2 and column.Length-2. Save the row/column when the result is higher than the previous maximum sum.

Comment: You need to check item below, under, left and right. You can do it by for example: [i+1, j], [i-1, j+1] and so on. Just use index plus or minus 1. Don't forget to check if you will not point to index outside of array.

Comment: it sounds like all you need to do here is a: figure out how to sum *a single* sub-matrix, for example the one starting at position (x,y), b: write a loop over the two dimensions, taking the size of the sub-matrix into account, and calculate the sum of each possible sub-matrix, and c: pick the largest? I don't think people will want to do this *for you* (this sounds like homework, and you don't learn anything by not doing it) - so: where did you get to?

Comment: This is what you have tried to get sum https://stackoverflow.com/a/56225711/6299857... To find 2x2 matrix what you tried so far

Comment: @MarcGravell, I've updated my code. I'd be very grateful if you could see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check values only *current, under* positions of your **i** and *current, right* positions of your **j**.

I mean it will check like this:

- [7,1] [1,3] [3,3]
- [1,3] [3,9] [9,8]

And so on.

After every compare, calculate sum of this 2x2 matrix and save it to dictionary.
For return, you just need to find the max value of key and get value of it key.

```
public class MatrixTest
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData =>
            new List<object[]>
            {
                new object[]
                {
                    new int[,]
                    {
                        {7, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1},
                        {1, 3, 9, 8, 5, 6},
                        {4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 0}
                    },
                    new int[,]
                    {
                        {9, 8},
                        {7, 9}
                    },
                    33
                },
                new object[]
                {
                    new int[,]
                    {
                        {10, 11, 12, 13},
                        {14, 15, 16, 17}
                    },
                    new int[,]
                    {
                        {12, 13},
                        {16, 17}
                    },
                    58
                }
            };


        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
        public void Test(int[,] input, int[,] expectedArray, int expectedSum)
        {
            MatrixHandler m = new MatrixHandler();

            var resp = m.GetMax2x2Matrix(input);

            resp.Item1.Should().Be(expectedSum);

            resp.Item2.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedArray);
        }
    }


    public class MatrixHandler
    {
        public (int, int[,]) GetMax2x2Matrix(int[,] source)
        {
            var sumsPlusTempArrays = new Dictionary<int, int[,]>();

            int[,] temp;
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0, n0 = source.GetLength(0) - 1; i <= n0; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0, n1 = source.GetLength(1) - 1; j <= n1; j++)
                {
                    if (i + 1 <= n0 && j + 1 <= n1)
                    {
                        temp = new int[2,2];
                        temp[0, 0] = source[i, j];
                        temp[0, 1] = source[i, j + 1];
                        temp[1, 0] = source[i + 1, j];
                        temp[1, 1] = source[i + 1, j + 1];
                        sum = CalculateSum(temp);
                        sumsPlusTempArrays.TryAdd(sum, temp);
                    }
                }
            }

            var key = sumsPlusTempArrays.Select(x => x.Key).Max();

            var value = sumsPlusTempArrays[key];

            return (key, value);
        }

        private int CalculateSum(int[,] source)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0, n0 = source.GetLength(0); i < n0; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0, n1 =  source.GetLength(1); j < n1; j++)
                {
                    sum += source[i, j];
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```